# Best Practices : JSON for data exchange for RESTful web services using apache CXF

Tags: java, json, web-services, rest, cxf

I have a prototype for a RESTful web service using Apache CXF. I am using json for the data exchange between client and server. currently there are several pojos which are mapped to several request and response JSON needed for different scenarios.

My concern is, if the number of scenarios increase in future we will have to additional pojos for request and response. Is there any other way of doing it?

Answer (score 1):

Are all these pojos have same type of behavior??? if yes then we can create an interface, all pojos should implement this interface. We can  initialize object at runtime based on pojo class name.

you can use this code for runtime initialization. -

```
INTERFACE_CLASS_NAME  interface_identifier=(INTERFACE_CLASS_NAME)Class.forName(POJO_CLASS_NAME_WITH_PACKAGE).newInstance();
```

You can use third party library like Gson to convert pojo to json or vice-versa.

Comment: when you say same behaviour you mean by their parameters< rite? Also the conversion from pojo to json and vice-versa is handled itself by the CXF apis. i just want to know if there is any other option than  really using the POJOs.

Comment: Behaviour means they have same method name and instance variables(as defined in Interface) but those method have different implementation for different pojos.
I think you want to map all pojo dynamically to json (as they increase in future).
So to refer any pojo's object we need some variable reference, so by using interface we can specify  variable reference which will refer any of dynamic pojo's object.